# regex to get word between two undescores

Tags: java, regex

I've a line like `bla_bla**_**test**_1**023`

and would like to extract the word between `_` and any underscore followed by digit `_digit` which is `test` in the above example.

I've tried the following regex but unfortunately does not work:
`[^_ ]+(?=[ _\d])` - it getting me all words before "_digit" not only the one which is before `_digit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. Use `Pattern` and `Matcher` with *look-arounds*.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word= "bla_bla_test_1023";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=_)([^_]+)(?=_\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(word);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }


}
```

O/P :

> test

Comment: Is the lookbehind necessary?

Comment: @JimW - Technically No. You could capture it and use `m.group(1)` instead of `m.group()` to get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [^_]*(?=_\d)
```

You want to match everything other than _ until you get to _ followed by a digit.