# Regex, find character between two specific words, right before second word

Tags: regex, bash, awk, markdown

I have been trying but without much success with [capture a word between two words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405337/regex-capture-a-word-between-two-words) and [Get Word Between two underscores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013824/regex-to-get-word-between-two-undescores) among many many others...

I want to find the newline before "##", this "##' is after '## baba' but not right after, there is some text between. They are many "##" in the file, always preceded by \n. See below schema:

#### Current input file

```
##

## baba

rosa rosa rosam rosae ipsum


##

##
```

Once it is found insert "helloworld" given as an argument to the script

#### Desired output

```
##

## baba {could also be "foo" or "bar"}

rosa rosa rosam rosae ipsum

helloworld


##

##
```

I went as close as what I want with the following script.sh:

```
awk -i inplace -v foo=$2 -v new=$1'\n\n' '
    f&&/^##/{print new; f=0} {print} /^## baba/{f=1}
' a.md
```

I want two last things:

1. to replace baba with argument $2 (variable foo),
2. to include the \n in ^## to have it one line above.

Thank you very much for any help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiastic programmers. Add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Please add the expected output and your attempt to your question to make it complete. See [ask]. It's unlikely a regex will be the right solution - [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). Also - sed is the best tool when you have to do s/old/new/ on an individual string, it's highly unlike that it'd be the best tool for anything involving multiple lines - awk is a far more likely candidate.

Comment: it could be helloworld or something else, I use $1 to use a specific wording.
then I want to replace baba with argument $2 (variable foo). Also please upvote the question. I got bashed because my question was originally poorly written! It would help the visibility if not negative with two close...

Comment: The question is still surprisingly vague, I think because you're still trying to describe a regexp to solve the problem rather than describing the actual problem. I updated it best I could to try to clear it up but please check to see if now says what you wanted to say. You seem to want to insert the line `helloworld` 2 blank lines before the first line containing `## baba` after a line containing `##` was seen, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regex101.com when trying to use UNIX tools usually causes more confusion than it does solve problems since the regexp variants it supports don't match those of the standard UNIX tools. You still haven't posted your expected output so I'm guessing that this is what you want:

```
$ awk -v new='helloworld' 'f&&/^##/{print new; f=0} {print} /^## baba/{f=1}' file
##




## baba



{append or replace with -> helloworld here}
helloworld
##

##
```

Comment: Also I would like to include hello world one \n above but ```^\n##``` does not work

Comment: Again - **please** include the expected output in your question so there's no possibility of misunderstanding your needs.